# Hide a password in selenium IDE

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, selenium-ide, qa-role

My client uses simple Selenium IDE scripts for regression testing. The issue is that when the scripts are shared, people's AD usernames and passwords are shared too.

I'm trying to put a stop to this by having a test account created with a shared password but they're not convinced this is a better way to go because of the security risk. I realise it's the same thing as what they're doing now... but that's a different discussion.

Anyway, is possible to mask the password in the IDE or call an external file with the test username and password in? I think that would convince them to provide QA with a test account and not inherit the risk of fraudulent activity.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Why do not you use selenium webdriver instead of IDE?

Comment: They don't have the time, budget, resource, etc. to implement WebDriver at the moment. They have an existing library of very simple tests (login, verify a value, logout) and it's just the current setup. The client's always right ;)

Comment: P.S. By resource, I mean that testing's a new concept at the moment so only have functional, manual testers on-board at the moment. This might change in future but it's all they have for now!

Comment: As far as I know , there is no solution in selenium IDE to hide password.

Comment: The only quasi-solution would be to have a test/QA environment with a copy of production data, but all passwords changed to something known and standard. So even if people and scripts share passwords, they don't share PRODUCTION passwords.

Comment: I've said the same, @PeterMasiar. It'd require some changes at an infrastructure level because the Active Directory covers both live and test environments (so even the test accounts will have access to live). But as it's a Change Request coming from a new guy in the evil QA department... they're not inclined to do it! If Selenium doesn't support password masking then I may have to push for it anyway. Cheers!

Comment: testing with access to live production == making changes in PROD by mistake == disaster waiting to happen. Good luck, and **warn them in writing about inevitable coming disaster (not if, but when)** to CYA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried it myself, but it appears this [firefox addon SelBlocks](https://github.com/refactoror/SelBlocks)  has functions called `loadXmlVars` and `loadJsonVars`.

Found reference to this [in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416249/selenium-ide-read-file).

GL with that client.